# PHP - Breakdown Queries results to be able to use in while loop

Tags: php, graph, line

My Data looks like the following

```
Year   Month   Cause      Count
2014   8       Lookup     14
2014   8       Unplanned  10
2014   8       Late       2
2014   9       Class      1
2014   9       Lookup     10
2014   9       Unplanned  1
```

What I need to do is away to put this infomation in a while or some sort of loop so it can be added into the Google Line Graph data using php

so if I did a search for the months 8, 9 it would return a line graph which seperates the data to be used in a line graph broken down by cause and count for each month

that data will change on the fly when some searches by timeframe

My code

```
$data=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH))
{


$m=(stripslashes($row['the_month']));
$y=(stripslashes($row['the_year']));
$c=(stripslashes($row['the_cause']));
$t=(stripslashes($row['the_count']));
array_push ($data, $m ,$y, $c, $t);

}
?>
<pre>
<?php print_r($data); ?>
</pre>

Results

 Array
(
    [0] => 8
    [1] => 2014
    [2] => Lookup / Research request
    [3] => 14
    [4] => 8
    [5] => 2014
    [6] => account configuration
    [7] => 2
    [8] => 8
    [9] => 2014
    [10] => Custom Solution
    [11] => 2
    [12] => 8
    [13] => 2014
    [14] => Error Messages
    [15] => 1
    [16] => 8
    [17] => 2014
    [18] => API error
    [19] => 1
    [20] => 8
    [21] => 2014
    [22] => Unplanned outage
    [23] => 1
    [24] => 9
    [25] => 2014
    [26] => Lookup / Research request
    [27] => 11
    [28] => 9
    [29] => 2014
    [30] => API error
    [31] => 2
    [32] => 9
    [33] => 2014
    [34] => account configuration
    [35] => 2
    [36] => 9
    [37] => 2014
    [38] => Site error
    [39] => 1
)
```

Comment: Where does this data come from? [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: comes mysql database, i do a select and then group by year and month and get count of each cause